# idiomatic way to solve chicken-egg in scala

Tags: scala

How to nicely initialize structures like that:

```
case class A(name: String, b: B)
case class B(name: String, a: A)
```

Looking for solution without lazy vals (performance overhead) and without adding new members to existing case class (it just looks ugly), but special wrappers and changes of original type-signature maybe fine (at least it's the best I've got for now). toString-problem is negligible as I can override it in some trait.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I came up with this:

```
   case class Chicken[T](h: Holder[T, _]) {
     def get = h.chicken
     override def toString = get.toString
   }

   case class Egg[U](h: Holder[_, U]) {
     def get = h.egg
     override def toString = get.toString
   }

   implicit def egg[T] = (_: Egg[T]).get
   implicit def chicken[T] = (_: Chicken[T]).get

   case class Holder[U, T] (chickenF: (Egg[T], Chicken[U]) => (U, T)) {
     val (chicken, egg) = chickenF( Egg(this), Chicken(this))
   }

   def mutual[U, T](chickenF: (Egg[T], Chicken[U]) => (U, T)) = {
        val h = new Holder(chickenF)
        h.chicken -> h.egg
   }


   trait Named { //to avoid unfinite toString
       def name: String
       override def toString = name
   }
```

Usage:

```
case class A(name: String, b: Egg[B])
case class B(name: String, a: Chicken[A]) extends Named

val (a, b) = mutual[A, B](A("a", _) -> B("b", _))

val (a2, b2) = mutual[A, B]{ (b2, a2) => //alternative for complex cases
    A("a", b2) -> B("b", a2)    
}

println(a)
println(b)
println(a.b)
println(b.a)
```

Results:

```
A(a,b)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
b                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
A(a,b)
```

Still hope that there is a library for that, like scalaz or some-macro based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another way I found a while back to deal with this (although I now perfer to engineer my types such that these cyclic references don't come up), is to pass in a generator function for such values, rather than the value directly (or alternates like your `Chicken` and `Egg` types). Eg:

```
trait Named { //to avoid infinite toString, as before
  def name: String
  override def toString = name
}

case class A(name: String, generator: A => B) extends Named { val b: B = generator(this) }
case class B(name: String, a: A) extends Named // Either or both types could extend Named
```

Example usage:

```
scala> def generator(name: String)(a: A): B = B(name, a)
generator: (name: String)(a: A)B

scala> val a = A("a", generator("b"))
a: A = a

scala> a.b
res6: B = b
```

Comment: I don't have scala REPL installed to check if it inferrs a type correctly (seen my ugly printlns for online interpereter, ha? :) ), but maybe it could be better with val a = A("a", B("name", _)). For particular case like just two types involved, I would move generator and b into some trait (F-bounded probably as it should know about A). If it works, your solution seems better. P.S. Actually, I never faced that either, just seen several questions, when someone wants to have both parent/child links to look up them quickly, and navigate trees in more convenient way.

Comment: btw, egg and chickenin my version are just links to generator

Comment: @dk14 Oh yes, certainly, you can use `B("name", _)` as the generator value; you can wrap that, or any external generator function, into a factory method, class or trait; etc.